# CKAN Resource form html "Description" field, how/where can I change other fields to be the same size as description?

Tags: html, css, ckan

I am very new to CKAN and any kind of front-end. I have been searching through multiple html/css files and I can't find where I can change the size of the fields in the resources form. (Its where the user can change the metadata from GUI)

I want to change an extra field I made to the same size as the description field. Is anyone familiar with CKAN and knows the file name where I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename where resource fields are is inside [ckan/templates/package/snippets/resource_form.html](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/98f518c0587ae246eee3397fea7d19fc1f8a3d1a/ckan/templates/package/snippets/resource_form.html#L33). 
You can add your own html tags here or use one of the [macros](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/contributing/frontend/templating.html#form-textarea).
e.g

```
{{ form.textarea('desc', id='field-description', label=_('Description'), value=data.desc, error=errors.desc, classes=['your-class') }}
```

Inside classes label you can add array of classes to apply to the control-group.